# jQuery If Statement Problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

I was just having a couple more problems on a reaction test I was making. For some reason, the 'div' does not 'hide' when it is clicked. I basically want it so that after it is clicked, there is a random pause, and then the 'div' appears again in the next specified position. I think the problem may lie in the following code.

```
    if (posctr = 1) {
        $div.css({
            top: 300,
            left: 150
        }).show();
    } else if (posctr = 2) {
        $div.css({
            top: 100,
            left: 600
        }).show();
    } else if (posctr = 3) {
        $div.css({
            top: 650,
            left: 400
        }).show();
    } else if (posctr = 4) {
        $div.css({
            top: 500,
            left: 150
        }).show();
    } else if (posctr = 5) {
        $div.css({
            top: 50,
            left: 400
        }).show();
    } else if (posctr = 6) {
        $div.css({
            top: 400,
            left: 100
        }).show();
    }
```

You can try it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/FWSc7/

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

EDIT: This is the latest version. I'm having problems with the 'div' appearing 7 times. http://jsfiddle.net/FWSc7/8/

Comment: You can pass an object to the css at the end. You only need to modify the top and left. Also, you could [try a switch](http://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/FWSc7/5/).

Answer (score 2):

1) You're using assignment operator `=` in if.else.. statements.

Change it to `==` **(equality comparison)** in all if statements

**For example:**

```
if (posctr == 1)
```

2) other than this, you have some errors which you can see in console (in Developer tools)

3) Wrong selectors

```
$div.hide();  //Wrong since you haven't declared any variable like this
```

So add this to your code

```
var $div = $('div');
```

Check the [**final fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/FWSc7/3/)

Comment: Ah okay thanks for that! It still seems like it is not working correctly, though. For some reason, you can only click the 'div' once, even though it's meant to let you click it 7 times.

Comment: @user2840892 No your final works correctly.  the div hides for a little time and then it shows.  it happens for 7 clicks

Answer (score 0):

You should use `==` instead of `=`

```
= is a declaration
== is a comparison
```

Answer (score 0):

Premising that the equality comparison is done via `==` (better if you use strict equality `===` anyway) and not by `=` (assignment), you could significantly reduce your redundant code by a simple array lookup

e.g.

```
var coords = {
   y : [0, 300, 100, 650, 500, 50, 400],
   x : [0, 150, 600, 400, 150, 400, 100]
}
```

and just write

```
$div.css({
    top: coords['y'][posctr],
    left: coords['x'][posctr]
}).show();
```

the code would be better maintainable and less error-prone

Comment: Thanks for that! I just updated it, however it is still only letting me click on the 'div' once. http://jsfiddle.net/FWSc7/7/